# title ObservableField default is app name

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I have created an `ObservableField` named title :

```
public ObservableField<String> title = new ObservableField<>("");
```

and I have a edit text with two way binding:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="title"
        android:text="@={model.title}"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
        app:backgroundTint="#3c3b3b" />
```

but when I lanch the app edit text is filled with app name!
why this happens? if I change the field name it will be fixed!

Comment: did you add the binding library  and ViewModelProvider implementation ?

Comment: @B.mansouri no I didn't use `ViewModel`.

Comment: the architecture components advice you to use a viewModel , then link the binding to that viewModel ==> your fields will work perfectly

Comment: @B.mansouri I know but databindig was introduced a year before architecture components so it works alone.

Comment: did you add your model variable to the layout ?

Comment: add the variable and remove the "=" before the @

Comment: @B.mansouri yes, As I said it works fine if I use another name for the variable but if I use `title` this problem occures.

Comment: what is you model code ?

Comment: @B.mansouri why sould I remove `=` before @ ? I want to use two way binding.

Comment: @B.mansouri what do you mean by model code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185749/discussion-between-b-mansouri-and-sajad-abbasi).